# Protractor element not visible

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor for automating testing in my angular2 app. Everything works fine, but i get an error element is not visible on my checkbox.

Someone knows why it works on my nickname textbox and not on my checkbox?

```
  <div class="form-item">
        <label for="nicknaam">nicknaam</label>
        <input  id="nicknaam" name="nicknaam" type="text" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-item">
        <input #termscb id="termscb" name="termscb" type="checkbox" (change)="pro.terms= (termscb.checked?'Y':'N')" />
        <label for="termscb">{{"settings.acceptour" |_}} <a class="" href="#modalTerms">{{"settings.terms" |_ }}</a></label>
      </div>






describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('http://localhost:4000/register');
    });


    it('create user', function() {

        element(by.id('nicknaam')).sendKeys("test");
        element(by.id('termscb')).click();

        browser.sleep(3000);
        element.all(by.buttonText('Validate')).click();

    });
});
```

Comment: Just put some wait between Sendkeys and Click and see , i.e.
 element(by.id('nicknaam')).sendKeys("test");
browser.sleep(3000);
        element(by.id('termscb')).click();

Comment: still not working with browser.sleep between them

Comment: Can you show me the error ?

Comment: here is a image [Link](http://i65.tinypic.com/2u44ri0.jpg)

Comment: Which item is failing, `element(by.id('termscb')).click();` or `element.all(by.buttonText('Validate')).click();` ?

Comment: I hope you have attach the correct link. Can you put the screenshot of that checkbox and please attach the error which you are getting.